# no matching function for call error & candidates error

Tags: c++, class

I have this class:

template

```
class MtmMap {

private:

    ValueType defaultValue;

    KeyType defaultKey;

    Node* head;

    int amount;

public:

    MtmMap(KeyType defaultKey, ValueType defaultValue) :

        defaultKey(defaultKey), defaultValue(defaultValue), head(NULL), amount(0) {

    } ;
....... more code.. };
```

and when I want to create a new class:

```
MtmMap<int, int> m ;
```

I have alot of errors:

```
- candidates are:

- no matching function for call to 'MtmMap<int,int>::MtmMap()'
```

*I have edit problims . . . sorry

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no constructor with no parameters. You have only constructor with 2 parameters. You can declare constructor without parameters, or you should construct your object with constructor with 2 params.

```
MtmMap m((KeyType()), (ValueType()));
```

You give it template parameters, that is not the same, that constructor parameters. Template parameters in your case are types and in constructor you should send values one of type `KeyType` and second of type `ValueType` (int, int in your case). For example like this

```
MtmMap<int, int> mmap(1, 2); // default key == 1, default value == 2
```

Comment: but I dont need it because I sent two parametrs ( int , int )

Comment: ok so if I wanna make a constructor that takes only the types how do I do it?

Comment: @user3036061 you cannot do this. Function cannot receive types as parameters.

Comment: but I want to creat a MtmMap with (int,int) but I want to put the acctual int value using "insert" function that I have created in the class that takes (KeyType k, ValueType v)

Comment: @user3036061 write constructor without params and all should be ok.

Comment: like this: ?
 MtmMap() :
   head(NULL), amount(0) {
 } ;
?

Answer (score 0):

```
MtmMap(KeyType defaultKey, ValueType defaultValue)
```

`MtmMap` has a constructor wich takes two parameters. you are passing none.

Comment: but I give it two parameters (int,int)
MtmMap<int, int> m ;